# How to call refFromURL in Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm storing references to files in Firebase Cloud Storage using URLs. In firebase client code, you can call `firebase.storage().refFromURL(photo.image)` to get the actual storage reference and do handy things like call delete with it. How do I accomplish the same thing in a cloud function (specifically a realtime database trigger)? I want to be able to clean up images after deleting the object that references them.

Answer (score 3):

Following [Bob Snider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45060805/11652243)'s answer, this is a little function (typescript) to extract file full path from URL.

```
export const getFileFromURL = (fileURL: string): Promise<any> => {
  const fSlashes = fileURL.split('/');
  const fQuery = fSlashes[fSlashes.length - 1].split('?');
  const segments = fQuery[0].split('%2F');
  const fileName = segments.join('/');

  return fileName;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In a cloud function, to delete a file from storage you need the file's bucket name and file name (which includes the path).  Those can be obtained on the client side from the storage reference.  For example, a [JS Storage Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference) has properties `bucket` and `fullPath`.  The string representation of a storage reference has format: `gs://example-12345.appspot.com/path/to/file`, where the bucket is `example-12345.appspot.com` and the file "name" is `path/to/file`.

In the example cloud function shown below, the client is expected to provide the bucket and filename as children of the trigger location.  You could also write the URL string to the trigger location and then split it into bucket and filename components in the cloud function.

This code is based on the example in the [Cloud Storage guide](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-basics).

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.deleteFile = functions.database.ref('/test').onWrite(event => {
  const bucket = event.data.child('bucket').val();
  const filename = event.data.child('filename').val();

  console.log('bucket=', bucket, 'filename=', filename);

  return gcs.bucket(bucket).file(filename).delete().then(() => {
     console.log(`gs://${bucket}/${filename} deleted.`);
   }).catch((err) => {
     console.error('ERROR:', err);
   });

});
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid storing multiple representations of the same data. The client allows you to go from URL to storage ref and I was hoping the server did the same...

Comment: @GregGilley:  I'm fairly certain there is no server-side object equivalent to the cliend-side storage ref.  But if you use [toString()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#toString) on a storage ref and store that in your DB, then you can split it to get the the needed bucket and name for deleting the file.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one-liner.

```js
const refFromURL = (URL) => decodeURIComponent(URL.split('/').pop().split('?')[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote code sample which I using instead `refFromURL` method from web-firebase in my functions project based on [Bob Snyder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45060805/2876310) answer.

```
function refFromUrl(gsLink) {
    var fileEntryTemp = gsLink.file.replace("gs://", "")
    var bucketName = fileEntryTemp.substring(0, fileEntryTemp.indexOf("/"));
    var filename = gsLink.file.match("gs://" + bucketName + "/" + "(.*)")[1];
    var gsReference = admin.storage().bucket().file(filename);
    return gsReference;
}
```

Here is an example how I get a download link based on this ref:

```
var gsReference = refFromUrl(fileEntry);

gsReference.getSignedUrl({
    action: 'read',
    expires: '03-09-2491'
    }).then(function (url) {
    console.log(url);
    response.send(url);
}).catch(function (error) {

});
```

Hope this will save time for somebody

Answer (score -3):

For complicated actions on your database from cloud functions you could use Admin SDK https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start
For the usage of Cloud Storage in Cloud Function check this out https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events
Cloud Functions may not provide the same capability as client since Cloud Functions is beta for now and people are still working on it.